# Docker compose stack does not start properly after reboot

Tags: docker

I'm trying to set up a tezos in docker. I followed [this](https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html) how to from the official tezos documentation.

Because I want to learn how tezos works (especially baking/staking) I will use babylonnet first.

Docker hosts OS is Ubuntu 18.04 with latest HWE enabled.

```
docker -v
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
```

```
docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe
```

I downloaded the start script like described in the how to.

After a

```
./bablyonnet start
```

the complete docker stack started. I had to wait some hours till chain was in sync. Then i could do some test transactions and so on like described in the how to. Just fine till this point.

Later the day I rebooted the docker host. And worked on a another project. But I had some strange DNS erros during the day. Later I found that my docker host made 227k dns request for host named node. This is caused because not all of the tezos docker conatiners were started after reboot. Especially the babylonnet_node_1 failed to start. Thats why docker tried to request the dns server.

This is how the tezos docker stack looks after ./babylonnet start

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                                NAMES
66d8eadb81c3        tezos/tezos:babylonnet   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                                                        babylonnet_accuser-005-PsBabyM1_1
977eccd4ca01        tezos/tezos:babylonnet   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                                                        babylonnet_baker-005-PsBabyM1-test_1
798be668561f        tezos/tezos:babylonnet   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                                                        babylonnet_baker-005-PsBabyM1_1
a41907e97a38        tezos/tezos:babylonnet   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                                                        babylonnet_endorser-005-PsBabyM1-test_1
d569a1709f20        tezos/tezos:babylonnet   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                                                        babylonnet_accuser-005-PsBabyM1-test_1
95bede3df7f6        tezos/tezos:babylonnet   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                                                        babylonnet_endorser-005-PsBabyM1_1
920656b54811        tezos/tezos:babylonnet   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Restarting (1) 3 seconds ago                                        babylonnet_upgrader_1
4fb95ada1d9a        tezos/tezos:babylonnet   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                   8732/tcp, 0.0.0.0:19732->19732/tcp   babylonnet_node_1
```

After reboot some of the containers are missing.

```
docker ps
IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
977eccd4ca01        tezos/tezos:babylonnet   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   7 minutes ago       Up 1 second                                         babylonnet_baker-005-PsBabyM1-test_1
a41907e97a38        tezos/tezos:babylonnet   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   7 minutes ago       Up 8 seconds                                        babylonnet_endorser-005-PsBabyM1-test_1
d569a1709f20        tezos/tezos:babylonnet   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 seconds                                        babylonnet_accuser-005-PsBabyM1-test_1
920656b54811        tezos/tezos:babylonnet   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   7 minutes ago       Restarting (1) 12 seconds ago                       babylonnet_upgrader_1
```

docker-compose.yml created by babylonnet.sh

```
~/.tezos-babylonnet$ cat docker-compose.yml 
version: "2"

volumes:
  node_data:
  client_data:

services:

  node:
    image: tezos/tezos:babylonnet
    hostname: node
    command: tezos-node --net-addr :19732 
    ports:
      - "19732:19732"
    expose:
      - "8732"
    volumes:
      - node_data:/var/run/tezos/node
      - client_data:/var/run/tezos/client
    restart: on-failure

  upgrader:
    image: tezos/tezos:babylonnet
    hostname: node
    command: tezos-upgrade-storage
    volumes:
      - node_data:/var/run/tezos/node
      - client_data:/var/run/tezos/client
    restart: on-failure

  baker-005-PsBabyM1:
    image: tezos/tezos:babylonnet
    hostname: baker-005-PsBabyM1
    environment:
      - PROTOCOL=005-PsBabyM1
    command: tezos-baker --max-priority 128
    links:
      - node
    volumes:
      - node_data:/var/run/tezos/node:ro
      - client_data:/var/run/tezos/client
    restart: on-failure

  endorser-005-PsBabyM1:
    image: tezos/tezos:babylonnet
    hostname: endorser-005-PsBabyM1
    environment:
      - PROTOCOL=005-PsBabyM1
    command: tezos-endorser
    links:
      - node
    volumes:
      - client_data:/var/run/tezos/client
    restart: on-failure

  accuser-005-PsBabyM1:
    image: tezos/tezos:babylonnet
    hostname: accuser-005-PsBabyM1
    environment:
      - PROTOCOL=005-PsBabyM1
    command: tezos-accuser
    links:
      - node
    volumes:
      - client_data:/var/run/tezos/client
    restart: on-failure

  baker-005-PsBabyM1-test:
    image: tezos/tezos:babylonnet
    hostname: baker-005-PsBabyM1-test
    environment:
      - PROTOCOL=005-PsBabyM1
    command: tezos-baker-test --max-priority 128
    links:
      - node
    volumes:
      - node_data:/var/run/tezos/node:ro
      - client_data:/var/run/tezos/client
    restart: on-failure

  endorser-005-PsBabyM1-test:
    image: tezos/tezos:babylonnet
    hostname: endorser-005-PsBabyM1-test
    environment:
      - PROTOCOL=005-PsBabyM1
    command: tezos-endorser-test
    links:
      - node
    volumes:
      - client_data:/var/run/tezos/client
    restart: on-failure

  accuser-005-PsBabyM1-test:
    image: tezos/tezos:babylonnet
    hostname: accuser-005-PsBabyM1-test
    environment:
      - PROTOCOL=005-PsBabyM1
    command: tezos-accuser-test
    links:
      - node
    volumes:
      - client_data:/var/run/tezos/client
    restart: on-failure
```

If I do a ./babylonnet stop and start again the docker stack will start properly.

I don't see an error in docker-compose file. What can I do to get this working? Maybe I'm using the wrong docker version?

Also container  babylonnet_upgrader_1 stays in status "Restarting" all the time. It seems that the entrypoint has a wrong parameter.

```
docker logs -f babylonnet_upgrader_1

Current public chain: 2019-09-27T07:43:32Z.
Local chain data: 2019-09-27T07:43:32Z.
tezos-node: unknown command `upgrade'.
Usage: tezos-node COMMAND ...
Try `tezos-node --help' for more information.
```

Maybe this issue should be discussed in an extra question.

Comment: you can checkout this docker-compose file here for comparison : https://gitlab.com/abate/training-2020-deploy/-/tree/master/examples_single

Answer (score 0):

The script you found in the official documentation hides many details that might make it difficult to debug. I personally don't advice to use that script in production.

There are two more ways to setup tezos with docker that are in development.

- The first one is `teztool`[1](https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/teztool) : this is still in beta, and it's going to replace the sh script you tried to use.
- The second is provisioning a VM via ansible using this [playbook](https://gitlab.com/abate/training-2020-deploy/-/tree/master/ansible) associated to this [role](https://gitlab.com/abate/ansible-nomadic-docker). Again this is in development, but feedback will be highly appreciated.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thx pietro. I tried both ansible and teztool. Ansible how to didn't work well. It is more alpha then beta. Teztool worked so far. I have a working node now. Which also in sync after some hours. Now I try to understand how I can bake some test tezos in babylonnet. I is there a good howto, The one from official docs seems to be outdated too.